# Building an application with a site's API

Tags: html, objective-c, xml, api

So I want to build an application in Objective C for a site that I use. Here is an example of their login API:

Verify Credentials

```
Allows authenticating user to check username/password.

URL:
http://myanimelist.net/api/account/verify_credentials.xml

Formats:
xml
HTTP Method(s):
GET

Requires Authentication:
true

Response:
Success: 200 status code, XML data for user.
Failure: 204 status code (no content).

Example Response:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<user>
    <id>1</id>
    <username>Xinil</username>
</user>            

Usage Examples:

    CURL:
    curl -u user:password http://myanimelist.net/api/account/verify_credentials.xml
```

`
More API [Here](http://myanimelist.net/modules.php?go=api#verifycred). If anyone can point me into the right apple documentation to use MyAnimeList's API it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at these examples, may be they will help you:

http://github.com/pigoz/imal
http://github.com/chikorita157/MAL-Client-OS-X-Rewrite
http://github.com/chikorita157/malupdaterosx

Comment: Amazing! Just what I was looking for.